# Alfresco 7.1.1 thumbnail not getting generated (Windows)

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

We have installed Alfresco 7.1.1 Enterprise version. Alfresco is working fine and we are able to preview documents in Share. However it is not generating the thumbnails for these documents.

When we tried to test the document transformation from the admin console, it shows the following error.

```
1             pdf  png  TestTransform.pdf 23.1 KB Local:pdfToImageViaPng
1             workspace://SpacesStore/2ead5401-59f6-49ef-8065-03a1bad1ee97 
1.1           pdf  png  TestTransform.pdf 23.1 KB Local:pdfrenderer
1.1                     Failed 01090029 pdfrenderer returned a 400 status All in One 
              Transformer - Transformer exit code was not 0: \nCannot run program 
      \"H:\\Alfresco-Transform-Service\\alfresco-pdf-renderer\": CreateProcess 
 error=5, Access is denied http://localhost:8090/transform targetExtension=png 
sourceEncoding=UTF-8 sourceMimetype=application/pdf sourceExtension=pdf targetMimetype=image/png
1                       Failed 01090030 Content conversion failed
1             Finished in 51 ms
```

We also has given modify and read & execute permissions to the **H:\Alfresco-Transform-Service\alfresco-pdf-renderer\alfresco-pdf-renderer.exe** file. We even tried to run the **tomcat**, **start-transform-core-aio.jar** and **activeMQ** as an Admin but still it gives the same error.

We have also installed the GhostScripts, however it is not mentioned anywhere on the Alfresco's website. :-(

Any help will be appreciated.. thanks

Comment: Ring support and ask for help - that's part of what your pay them all that money for Enterprise for!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the server machine needed to be restarted after the Windows upgrade. After restarting the server machine it started working.